# Counting Rooted Trees with Projective Property

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to count the number of rooted trees with a special property from dependency grammar parsing, known as projectivity. The formal definition is slightly complicated - it is most easily explained with an example:

Suppose we have three nodes labeled 1, 2, 3. By Cayley's Theorem, there are $3^{3-2}=3$ different trees formed from these 3 nodes; however, if we distinguish between trees if they have different roots (called rooted trees), then there are $3\cdot 3^{3-2}=3^{3-1}=9$ different trees. We can write these trees uniquely using dendogram type notation (with 1,2,3 placed in order), as you can see here:

[DendogramTrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZmI3.png)

The following trees are non-projective because they have a crossing when mapped to their corresponding dendograms:

[NonprojectiveTrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPV62.png)

These are the only non-projective trees when using 3 nodes. Thus there are 7 projective trees out of the 9 total trees when using 3 nodes.

**How many projective trees are there in the general case of $n$ nodes?**

We know by Cayley's Theorem that there are $n\cdot n^{n-2}=n^{n-1}$ total trees using $n$ distinct nodes, so we can either count the number of projective trees directly or count the number of non-projective trees and subtract from this total.

It seems as if induction would be appropriate here, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: I have the same question here. Hope someone can help here!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A006013